# Qualitative analysis of a separable ODE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the following differential equation $$x'=(x-1)(t^2-1)h(t)$$ where $h(t)\in C^0(\mathbb{R})$ and $h(t) > 0$. Prove that under the initial condition $x(3)=0$ the maximal interval for $t$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

---

For $t_+$ this is obvious because it is bellow the singular point and the solution is monotonically decreasing there. Now, for $t_-$ I used

$$\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x-1} = \int_{3}^{t_-}h(t)(t^2-1) \mathrm{d}t$$

$x$ goes to infinity so it diverges. But there is no other information about $h$ and I am kinda stuck, would love some help.